# Using Alerts in bootstrap causes content to move down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alert

Code : [Link to sample code in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vkLpsdj/5/)

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      #mynetwork {
        height :650px;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
      };

    </style>
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Content here -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Sample</a>
             <form class="d-flex" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();alert('Not found','warning');">
              <input class="form-control me-2" id="job_search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success"  >Search</button>

              </form>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="liveAlertPlaceholder" class="position-absolute"></div>     
        <div id="mynetwork"></div>

  
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     var alertPlaceholder = document.getElementById('liveAlertPlaceholder');
     function alert(message, type) {
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.innerHTML = '<div id="alert" class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">' + message + '<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button></div>';

        alertPlaceholder.append(wrapper);
        const alert = document.querySelector("#alert");
        // Create Bootstrap alert instance
        const bsAlert = new bootstrap.Alert(alert);

        // Dismiss time out
        setTimeout(() => {
          bsAlert.close();
        }, 2000);
    };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use the alert class in bootstrap and when it is displayed, the content below is pushed down. I used class="position-absolute" and it fixed the issue partially. Now it is displayed on the left corner above mynetwork. Is it possible to display the alert with the full width of the container as it worked before using position-absolute?

I have used a fixed height for mynetwork because I could not make it automatically take the size of the browser. My plan is to use visjs inside this. There is a bug in the height parameter in Visjs due to which I have hard coded the height here.

Answer (score 2):

If you give an absolute/fixed position for your alert using css, you can specify a z value which will make it appear on a layer over the top of the content instead of inserting in and pushing the content down. Something like this:

```
.flash-messages {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1010;
  top: 3rem;
  right: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```